# SetState fails in callback (via ComponentWillMount), on server only

Tags: reactjs

I need to render React components on the server for SEO. My component fetches data in `ComponentWillMount`, based on the query parameters - but on the server (Node 4.0.0), `SetState` fails in the request's callback. The error can be reproduced with a simpler `setTimeout` too, as in the code example below.

I have found numerous discussion on the web relating to complications between React and server-side rendering. I'm working on two work-around approaches:

- removing all ajax requests from the server, instead rendering the result of the request directly into a global variable embedded in the first-serve HTML
- moving the ajax request prior to initialization of the React components, on the server only (the request would still have to live in `ComponentWillMount` (or `ComponentDidMount`) for the client version.

Please let me know if there is an alternative or recommended approach instead.

```
var React = require('react');

// Reproduced in React 0.13.3 and 0.14.0-beta1
var ReactDOMServer = require("react-dom/server");

var A = React.createClass({
    componentWillMount: function() {
        var _this = this;
        // for example an ajax call to fetch data based on request parameters:
        setTimeout(function(err, res) {
            // state is set based on results
            _this.setState({ a: 1 });
        }, 100);
    },
    render: function() {
        return React.createElement('div', null);
    }
});

ReactDOMServer.renderToString(React.createElement(A, null));
```

Error:

```
$ node index.js 
/app/node_modules/react/lib/getActiveElement.js:25
    return document.body;
           ^

ReferenceError: document is not defined
    at getActiveElement (/app/node_modules/react/lib/getActiveElement.js:25:12)
    at ReactReconcileTransaction.ReactInputSelection.getSelectionInformation (/app/node_modules/react/lib/ReactInputSelection.js:38:23)
    at ReactReconcileTransaction.Mixin.initializeAll (/app/node_modules/react/lib/Transaction.js:168:75)
    at ReactReconcileTransaction.Mixin.perform (/app/node_modules/react/lib/Transaction.js:135:12)
    at ReactUpdatesFlushTransaction.Mixin.perform (/app/node_modules/react/lib/Transaction.js:136:20)
    at ReactUpdatesFlushTransaction.assign.perform (/app/node_modules/react/lib/ReactUpdates.js:86:38)
    at Object.flushBatchedUpdates (/app/node_modules/react/lib/ReactUpdates.js:147:19)
    at Object.wrapper [as flushBatchedUpdates] (/app/node_modules/react/lib/ReactPerf.js:66:21)
    at ReactDefaultBatchingStrategyTransaction.Mixin.closeAll (/app/node_modules/react/lib/Transaction.js:202:25)
    at ReactDefaultBatchingStrategyTransaction.Mixin.perform (/app/node_modules/react/lib/Transaction.js:149:16)
```

Issue opened at https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/4873

Answer (score -1):

Try moving the setState function in another method:

```
  var React = require('react');

  // Reproduced in React 0.13.3 and 0.14.0-beta1
  var ReactDOMServer = require("react-dom/server");
  var A = React.createClass({
    stateChange: function( obj ){
        setTimeout( this.setState( obj ), 100 );
    },
    componentWillMount: function() {
        this.stateChange( {a: 1} );
    },
    render: function() {
        console.log( this.state.a )
        return React.createElement('div', null);
    }
  }); 

  ReactDOMServer.renderToString(React.createElement(A, null));
```

Comment: hmmm... you're still getting the "ReferenceError: document is not defined" error? I'm getting 1 outputted in the console when I run node index.js.

Comment: I didn't copy your example correctly the first time - but now I see the difference. In your example, the '1' exists before the setTimeout callback. We are pretending the setTimeout is a return from a server ajax call, so the 1 is not known until we are inside the callback. So unfortunately your example is not a reproduction of the same problem.